# Is there a way to mirror faces without the normals being flipped?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, normals

I need to create a mirrored version of my mesh. In edit mode I press <kbd>M</kbd> plus the axis. But the normals on the mirrored faces are flipped, so I have to select all faces and recalculate/flip the normals.

I want to eliminate the last step. Is there a way to make the mirror function keep the normal direction of the original faces?

Comment: I don't think there is.

Comment: @Millard is right, unless you use the mirror modifier, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the mirror modifier is a good way to mirror an object and it solves your problem.